# How do I import web3 library from es6 module in browser?

Tags: web3js

Neither of these work:

`import { Web3 } from 'https://www.unpkg.com/web3@1.6.1/dist/web3.min.js';`

nor this:

`import Web3 from 'https://www.unpkg.com/web3@1.6.1/dist/web3.min.js';`

I can import other modules this way in the browser no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it from esm.sh:

`import Web3 from 'https://cdn.esm.sh/v58/web3@1.6.1/es2021/web3.js';`